# Multi AJAX requests inside a loop and building an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, .when

I'm completely stuck. I want to accomplish the following:
Update the shopping cart with the correct price agreements while logging in and out.

1. Get current cartlines from LocalStorage (successful)
2. With every cartline an AJAX request (getJSON for example) to get back the new data that applies at that moment. (Success)
3. Create a new object and save the new data.
4. Add the new object to the array.
5. When all AJAX requests are ready and the new array (new_cart) is completely filled, then push it to LocalStorage again.

Below my script. I hope someone can help me on my way.

```
function sync() {

// Read LocalStorage
try {
  var dataArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage('cartarray'));
}
catch (err) {
  var dataArray = null;
}

ary1 = dataArray.cartlines;

var keys = Object.values(ary1);
        
        
// Delete LocalStorage
// unsetLocalStorage('cartarray');
        
new_cart1 = [];
$.each( keys, function( index, value ){  
    var itemUrl = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/search/?sku=" + value.sku;
    var value1 = value.quantity;
    var p = $.getJSON(itemUrl);

    p.then(function(data) {
        var obj = {};
        
        // Add items
        obj['sku'] = data.results[0].sku;
        obj['quantity'] = value1;
        obj['price'] = data.results[0].price;
        obj['title'] = data.results[0].product_title;
        obj['img'] = data.results[0].img;
        obj['url'] = data.results[0].url;
        obj['internalSku'] = data.results[0].sku;

        // Return obj
        return obj;
    });
  
    // Add to object to array.
    new_cart1.push(obj);
});
        

$.when.apply($, new_cart1).then(function() { 
    var keys1 = new_cart1;
    var cartarray1 = [];
            
    for (var key of keys1) {
        console.log(key);
        if(key.quantity >= 1){
            cartarray1.push({
                sku: key.sku, 
                title: key.title,
                price: key.price,
                img: key.img,
                url: key.url,
                quantity: key.quantity,
                internalSku: key.internalSku,
                // custom: key.custom
            }); 
        }   
    }
    // setLocalStorage('cartarray', '{"cartId": "","cartlines":'+JSON.stringify(cartarray)+'}');
});
}
```

Comment: You can _promisify_ `$.getJSON` and request hadler, then use `Promise.all` to wait until everything returns response from server, after which you can process all returned results.

Comment: @fen1x can you provide me the structure of the code to run? Then I understand how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all much simpler if you think of each item being a single `async` method

```
async function processItem(value) {
    var itemUrl = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/search/?sku=" + value.sku;
    var data = await $.getJSON(itemUrl);

    return {
       sku: data.results[0].sku,
       quantity: value.quantity,
       price: data.results[0].price,
       title: data.results[0].product_title,
       img: data.results[0].img,
       url: data.results[0].url,
       internalSku: data.results[0].sku
    };        
}
```

Then waiting for them all is as simple as doing `Promise.all` on the result of a `map` to get the values. The below runs them all concurrently and waits for all results to complete.

```
async function execute(){ 
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage('cartarray'));
    var values = Object.values(dataArray.cartlines);
    var new_cart1 = await Promise.all(values.map(processItem));

    // do something with new_cart1 which is an array of 
    // the objects returned from processItem
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, how did you learn this? This is another way of thinking and working very well.

Comment: @nhatimme I've just been writing code a looooooooong time.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume you want:

1. You already have some `dataArray`
2. You wish to request additional data **in parallel** from server for each item
3. After all requests are completed you wish to process results

`$.getJSON` method returns [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, which implements the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) interface, so you can use it either this way:

```
$.getJSON(someUrl).then(result => {
    // do something with result
});
```

or this way (inside `async` function):

```
const result = await $.getJSON(someUrl);
// do something with result
```

Next step is to make your item processing async:

```
async function processItem(item) {
    return await $.getJSON(item.url);
}
```

And process whole array in parallel:

```
async function processArray(array) {
    const promises = array.map(processItem);
    return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Note that `Promise.all` resolves to an array with results for each item, and order of *results* is the same as order in initial array of `promises`.

Below is complete snippet that processes array asynchronously and waits until processing is finished. Note that I created `asyncGetJson` placeholder function in my snippet to simulate real server request with timeout:

```js
// Helper function to simulate random request timeout
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

/**
 * Not a real request, just a placeholder
 * This function multiplies n by 2 and returns it after random timeout
 */
function asyncGetJson(n) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(n * 2);
    }, getRandomInt(500, 2000));
  });
}

async function processItem(item) {
  return await asyncGetJson(item);
}

async function processArray(dataArray) {
  const promises = dataArray.map(processItem);
  return await Promise.all(promises);
}

async function init() {
  const dataArray = [1, 2, 3];

  console.log('Start');
  const result = await processArray(dataArray);
  console.log(result);
  console.log('Done');

  // Here should be your logic that works with results from the server
}

init();
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` already returns a promise, no need to wrap it in another. _As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.getJSON() implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise_ https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @Jamiec Thx, I did not know that.